# Detect if app opened x-times

Tags: xcode, swift

How can I detect if the app has been opened ex: 10 times, and then do a popup window action?

Maybe something in here:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if the most efficient so I'll just drop a comment, but maybe save the number of times the app has been opened to NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact use case, you can put something like this into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or `applicationDidBecomeActive`

```
let i = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("numLaunches")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(i+1, forKey: "numLaunches")
```

Then use that value to perform whatever action you need. The very first time this is called, `i` will be 0, so take that into account with whatever logic you implement. Also, make sure to synchronize your defaults.